# UART performance for real-time operations

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, uart, serial-communication

I am at my very first steps of building my setup which include Arduino and Raspberry-PI.

I am trying to figure out what will be the method to communicate between them.

Currently I am probing the Serial port communication method.

Is that a good enough method for communication between the two devices?

The communication is going to be used for real-time operations, not for debugging.

Is UART latency/performance good for that?

Some basic functional operations:

- control motors from PI to Arduino
- fetch sensors from Arduino to PI

Note: for now i can only think of the basic functional above, but i don't want my communication method to block me from achieving more complicated functional.

Comment: I think this question fits the scope of [EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) better than that of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you anustart! the site your shred seems like a great place for some of my questions. thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, serial communication is as fast as other interfaces, and faster then software-implemented ones.
If you use the hardware serial port and use a baud rate of.. let's say.. 115200 b/s, you can get a throughput of around 10 kB/s. Full duplex. If you have to go faster.. Probably you will have to use a more powerful board.
But if you have to measure mechanical parameters (motors, movements and so on) usually your time will be in the range of the millisecond, so a serial connection is ok.
If you have to go faster.. probably you will need another board.

Comment: Tnx! I don't have reputation for vote up :) can you comment on latency? TP is fine. But I get bad latency with my arduibo 1sec

Comment: Latency for serial communication is 1 byte. As for your problem, probably if you have a 1 second delay it's because the program is stuck somewhere (e.g. a delay or some other wait instructions).